# Solr Fuzzy search does only case sensitive searches

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

My database contains fist_name as 'Sumit' and when i search it gives me result for following first_name:Sumit~0.7 / first_name:Sumits~0.7

But it does not return anything if I tried for case insensitve search like
-first_name:SUMIT~0.7 / first_name:SUMit~0.7

My schema.xml contents are:

```
    <fieldType name="custum_fuzzy_text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
     <analyzer type="index"> 
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Can anyone help? Am I doing something wrong? Or Do I have do something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers)

```
On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word.
```

As no analysis is done at query time for fuzzy searches and hence the lower case filter would be applied during query time.
You would need to handle it at Client side.

Comment: is any of the above answered your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Solr are you using? This is quite important. Also, are you actually doing a fuzzy query with '*' (like Summit*) or just normal text. Those two cases are different as well.

If you are doing '*' query and your Solr is before 3.6, then you are hitting [the MultiTerm issue](http://searchhub.org/2011/11/29/whats-with-lowercasing-wildcard-multiterm-queries-in-solr/) (technical name for Fuzzy).

If you are not using *, I am not sure what the problem is. With Solr 4, the Admin interface has Analyser section where you can put your text against a field definition and see what comes out. Try that.

Finally, just as a note, if your index and query analyzer set is the same, you don't need to write it twice, just have one combined analyzer section (without type=...)

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre that helped a lot.